# Enable custom logo upload if logo is not in header

Tags: php, images, templates, uploads, logo

I am making a web site (a theme) in WordPress with logo which is not located in header area, but bellow header, on `front-page.php` (home page) instead. Is there any way to allow user to upload custom logo image instead of the current one?

I've seen many tutorials on how to do allow custom header logo upload, but the problem is, my logo is, as I said, on the page area below header area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question well, you already use [WordPress Custom Logo](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo), but you want a different logo on your front page. This means you will need to upload a separate image.

Assuming you already know how to use the customizer in general you will need to [build an upload field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Upload_Control) like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'wpse238690_front_logo', 
    array(
        'label'       => __( 'First image', 'wpse215632_theme' ),
        'description' => __( 'More about first image', 'wpse215632_theme' ),
        'section'     => 'wpse238690__section_id',
        'settings'    => 'wpse238690__setting_id',
    ) ) 
);
```

Replace the section and setting to fit the control in the right place in your customizer system.

In your header template you must then include a conditional with `is_front_page`: display the normal logo in the header if you're not on the front page. In your front page template include the logo with `get_mod('wpse238690_front_logo')`.

Comment: You are right, I am using WordPress Custom Logo. Will this code make my custom logo image show where I need it? Can I upload this code to functions.php? Excuse my questions, I am  a newbie.

Comment: Logos will show in the place where you include them in your template. It will not happen automatically.

Comment: Understood. I did as you instructed and it works. Thank you for your time and help!